# How can I compress a python script to exe (with its necessary files)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I want to compress a python script to onefile exe with pyinstaller.
My script needs also some other resources (some png photos and some ttf fonts), how do I compress them all to one executable?

I've tried `datas=[('C:/path/to/res/', '.')]` in a `.spec` file, but didn't work as expected. I mention that I've set "windowed" and "onefile" options.

A secvence of code where I use a png: `background: url(res/bg.png) no-repeat;`

(Python 3.7.1, PyInstaller 3.4, Windows 10 x64)

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work as expected"?

Comment: I'm trying to make a PyQt5 GUI. Didn't work as expected means that after I've done that, the executable still needed those photos and fonts to work correctly.

Comment: I believe the datas that you add must be files, not directories. For example: `datas=[('C:/path/to/res/*', '.')]` or `datas=[('relative/path/to/res/*', '.')]`

Comment: @JohnAnderson I've tried now, again, but not as I expected, still need those files to run correctly.